# How do I keep thread from hanging on when process completes (java)?

Tags: java-threads

This process runs hundreds of times a day. When server's host runs a clean up on the server, once a week, because the thread is getting hung, it causes the system to shutdown for up to 10 minutes and often self corrects but occassionaly the server must be restarted.  How do I ensure the thread is closed after each completion?

@SlingServlet(paths = "/bin/updateoliccart", methods="POST", metatype=true)
public class UpdateOLICCart extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7900366622715395681L;

protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpdateOLICCart.class);

@Reference
private ProcessApplication PA;

@Reference
private UpdatePayStatus updatePayStatus;

@Override
protected void doPost(final SlingHttpServletRequest req,
        final SlingHttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException   {
    Date dateStart = new Date();
    
    HttpSession httpsession = req.getSession();

    if(httpsession.isNew()){
        log.error("Session was broken");
        resp.sendRedirect("/content/wadoh/posterror.html");
    }else{

        String userType = (String)httpsession.getAttribute("userType");

        String draftIDFull = (String)httpsession.getAttribute("draftIDFull");   
        
        String payStatus = updatePayStatus.getDraftProperty(draftIDFull, "paystatus", req.getRemoteUser());
        
        log.error("The paystatus in Update OLIC Cart Servlet for user  " + req.getRemoteUser() + " is " + payStatus);


        if (!payStatus.equals("paymentreceived")){
            
            if(userType.contains("facility")){//begin facility applicant
                resp.getWriter().write(PA.updateFacilityCart(req).toString());
                resp.getWriter().flush();
                resp.getWriter().close();
            }
            else if(userType.contains("applicant")){//begin singular applicant
                resp.getWriter().write(PA.updateApplicantCart(req).toString());
                resp.getWriter().flush();
                resp.getWriter().close();
            }
            else{
                //unexpected result
                log.error("Unexpected User Type");
            }
        }
        else{
            resp.sendRedirect("/content/wadoh/posterror.html");
        }
    }
    
    Date dateStop =  new Date();
    long diff = dateStop.getTime() - dateStart.getTime();

    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    log.info("UpdateOLICCart Servlet complete for:" + req.getRemoteUser() + " Completed in:" + diffSeconds);
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: What web container are you using?  Tomcat? Glassfish? Something else?

Comment: @Stephen Tomcat